# Is it possible to store a password in firefox, when request in XUL application?

Tags: passwords, xul, firefox-addon

I'm developing xul extension that has access to a remote system.
User must set username and password in xul modal window to get access into the system, but firefox doesn't recognize that user has insert password and doesn't pourpose to save it.

Is there some method to save it via firefox, or have I to build some function to store password into my xul extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_nsILoginManager